the problem with learning the LSTM neural network
I need to create a model that will predict the error of some signal in time, i.e. solving the time series regression problem. I use LSTM for this:
class MyLSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, seq_length):
        super(MyLSTM, self).__init__()
        self.num_classes = num_classes 
        self.num_layers = num_layers 
        self.input_size = input_size 
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size 
        self.seq_length = seq_length 

        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size = input_size, hidden_size = hidden_size, num_layers = num_layers, batch_first = True) 
        self.fc_1 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, 128) 
        self.fc_2 = nn.Linear(128, num_classes) 
        self.activatin_func = nn.Tanh()
   

 def forward(self, x):
        h_0 = Variable(torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size)) 
        c_0 = Variable(torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size)) 
        out, (hn, cn) = self.lstm(x, (h_0, c_0)) 
        hn = hn.view(-1, self.hidden_size) 
        out = self.activatin_func(hn)
        out = self.fc_1(out) 
        out = self.fc_2(out) 
        out = self.activatin_func(out)
        return out  

Hyperparameters:
num_epochs = 1000 
learning_rate = 0.01 

input_size = X.shape[1] 
num_classes = y.shape[1] 
   
hidden_size = 16 
num_layers = 1 


As a result, I get a fairly accurate approximation of the model estimates at the training stage and a discrepancy at the testing stage. This seems rather strange to me, because the training is quite successful and the evaluated function does not have sharp jumps in values at the prediction stage and the evaluation curve should be close enough to the real value, but in practice I get sharp jumps, the nature of which I do not understand.
What could be the problem?
